# A synonym for esplanade

Tags: word-request

I read the word [esplanade](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/esplanade) might not common anymore, so I would like to ask a synonym used commonly for it?

Can I name it as a *coast-road*, a road made by concrete or chemicals by sea that for only walking or cycling ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Esplanade** does have an old-fashioned ring to it, but only by association with old-fashioned seaside towns. if you happen to live in, or be visiting, an old-fashioned seaside town, it's a perfectly satisfactory word to use.

The word [promenade](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/promenade) seems about right:

> A paved public walk, typically one along the seafront at a resort.

The word [corniche](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/corniche) could also be used, but the official definition doesn't quite fit:

> A road cut into the edge of a cliff, especially one running along a coast.

The term **coast-road** is probably a bit too general: it could be applied to any road that runs along a coast. The one that immediately springs to mind would be [route 101](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Route_101), which is definitely not just for walking or cycling.

Comment: To my ear, ***promenade*** is just as old-fashioned as ***esplanade***. So far as I'm concerned, ***seafront*** is completely current, and accurate enough.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: agreed about promenade but, as I said, I think that esplanade is also OK. This definition of seafront https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/seafront doesn't really fit the idea of **a road ... made only for walking or cycling**, but I'm inclined to agree with you if it's just as a general description of where you walked.

Comment: Obviously for those learners who have the time and energy to learn *everything* about English (including, but not limited to overtones of "old-fashioned rings"; it's sometimes feasible to park your car on an ***esplanade***, but never on a ***promenade***), it could be worth knowing how to use all three words. But for those who I assume are the *majority* coming here to ELL, it's more a matter of alerting them to the fact that if they're only going to learn *one* of these words, they should learn ***seafront*** and use it for all relevant senses.